# Generating iCal with PHP - Daylight Saving Issue

Tags: php, icalendar

I've seen several similar questions but as far as I can tell I'm doing this right.

I'm trying to use a PHP script to create a calendar reminder that takes into account UK Daylight Saving Time. We are currently in Daylight Saving time and the calendar reminder generated shows an hour ahead. Whatever value I put into the TZOFFSET doesn't seem to adjust the time either way.

Any help would be massively appreciated:

```
    echo 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR'."\r\n";
echo 'VERSION:2.0'."\r\n";
echo 'PRODID:-//bookingtest.co.uk'."\r\n";
echo 'METHOD:REQUEST\n';
echo 'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN'."\r\n";

echo 'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE'."\r\n";
echo 'TZID:Europe/London'."\r\n";
echo 'TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/Europe/London'."\r\n";
echo 'X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/London'."\r\n";

echo 'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT'."\r\n";
echo 'TZOFFSETFROM:+0100'."\r\n";
echo 'TZOFFSETTO:+0200'."\r\n";
echo 'TZNAME:BST'."\r\n";
echo 'DTSTART:19700329T010000'."\r\n";
echo 'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU'."\r\n";
echo 'END:DAYLIGHT'."\r\n";

echo 'BEGIN:STANDARD'."\r\n";
echo 'TZOFFSETFROM:+0100'."\r\n";
echo 'TZOFFSETTO:+0000'."\r\n";
echo 'TZNAME:GMT'."\r\n";
echo 'DTSTART:19701025T020000'."\r\n";
echo 'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU'."\r\n";
echo 'END:STANDARD'."\r\n";

echo 'END:VTIMEZONE'."\r\n";

echo 'BEGIN:VEVENT'."\r\n";
echo 'DTEND:'; echo dateToCal($dateend).'Z'."\r\n";
echo 'UID:'; echo uniqid()."\r\n";
echo 'DTSTAMP:'; echo dateToCal(time()).'Z'."\r\n";
echo 'LOCATION:'; echo escapeString($address)."\r\n";
echo 'DESCRIPTION:'; echo escapeString($description)."\r\n";
echo 'URL;VALUE=URI:'; echo escapeString($uri)."\r\n";
echo 'SUMMARY:'; echo escapeString($summary)."\r\n";
echo 'DTSTART:'; echo dateToCal($datestart).'Z'."\r\n";

echo 'BEGIN:VALARM'."\r\n";
echo 'TRIGGER:-PT2H'."\r\n";
echo 'ACTION:DISPLAY'."\r\n";
echo 'DESCRIPTION:'; echo escapeString($summary)."\r\n";
echo 'END:VALARM'."\r\n";

echo 'END:VEVENT'."\r\n";
echo 'END:VCALENDAR'."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

After a bit of messing about I worked it out. I just needed to remove the 'Z' off of the end of the DTSTART AND DTEND in the VEVENT to stop it forcing it into GMT and not Daylight Saving.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
echo 'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT'."\r\n";
echo 'TZOFFSETFROM:+0100'."\r\n";
echo 'TZOFFSETTO:+0200'."\r\n";
echo 'TZNAME:BST'."\r\n";
```

when it should be FROM +0000 to +0100.

Then dont see the full event so we have to assume that you are correctly referencing the TZID in your DTSTART/DTEND

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that but it's still an hour out as if it's not adjusting for Daylight Saving. I've updated the question to include the full event information, any idea why this might be?